# How to do mp4 video compression

Tags: android, video, compression

I am refer this link for the video compression..https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor when I compress .mkv file its works and gives smaller size  but when I compress .mp4 file it gives higher size than original size of video..I am not understand what changes i have to do for making this happen...this code uses the MediaCodec for the video compressor..and is it possible to do compression fast?

Comment: The resulting file size depends only on the bitrate (or target quality) and the duration of the video. Usually you can set the target bitrate or at least select among several presets.

Comment: changing the bitrate reduced the size of compressed video ..can u tell me how to do compression fast...@ggf31416

Answer (score 0):

mkv and mp4 are just video container file formats, to multiplex compressed video data and audio data into one file. You should check what's the video compression format (H.264, H.265 etc. ) inside mkv or mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Simply put the condition before calling the compression function.
Check the selected video height and width using MediaMetaDataRetriever and set if condition.

```
public void compress() {

    Log.w("VideoMessage","eNTERED : "+inputPath);
    lMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(inputPath);
    String lVideoWidth = lMediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
    Log.w("VideoMessage","VideoWidth: "+lVideoWidth);
    String lVideoHeight = lMediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    Log.w("VideoMessage","VideoHeight: "+lVideoHeight);
    if(Integer.valueOf(lVideoWidth)<=640 || Integer.valueOf(lVideoHeight)<=360){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video Already in compressed form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        try2CreateCompressDir();
        outPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator
                + APP_DIR
                + COMPRESSED_VIDEOS_DIR
                +"VIDEO_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + ".mp4";

        new VideoCompressor.execute(inputPath,outPath);

    }
}
```